# Expected repeatability of PT100 temperature sensor

Tags: sensor, noise, temperature, voltage-measurement

I'm designing a circuit to measure temperature using a PT100 sensor.

I'm putting 1mA through the sensor, and measuring the voltage drop. Assuming a perfect voltage measurement, what would be the repeatability of the measurement?

I'm thinking that any PT100 sensor is going to have a ridiculously good inherent repeatability and very low noise, and that all noise will come from the voltage measurement circuit, cables etc. Am I right in thinking this, or is there significant inherent noise in the PT100 element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are putting 1mA thru the PT100 you might get a little bit of self-heating error. 1mA into 100 ohms (0degC) produces a power of 100 uW - not much of course but you are asking about errors in your question.

You might also get spurious thermocouple errors due to dissimilar metals making contact and being heated at different temperatures. It's hard to rule out anything in this area and typically a k type thermocouple produces 41 uV per degC so, some random dissimilar-metal connection might be one-tenth of this and, if at some elevated temperature compared to the rest of the system could produce errors of a few hundred micro volts.

Regards noise - it's a resistor and behaves like any other resistor re thermal noise BUT, mechanically it's more like a strain gauge and therefore mechanical stress can affect its reading.

Comment: I suppose neither self heating nor thermocouple effects should affect repeatability? Or is there some inherent noise in a thermocouple as well? I'm only supplying current when measuring, so self-heating should be insignificant in my application.